# Writing to remaining_accounts in Anchor

Tags: anchor

I am currently experimenting Anchor, as I need to pass in an arbitrary number of accounts I am leveraging `remaining_accounts`.

### Client Side

```
await program.methods.someMethod().accounts({
  // somme accounts
})
.remainingAccounts([
  {
    isSigner: false,
    isWritable: true,
    pubkey: pub key
  }
])
.rpc();
```

Notice that the accounts in `remaining_accounts` are actually PDAs owned by my program, so I have the authority needed to write to them.

### On Chain

Now in order to make my life easier I deserialize the account by using my PDA Account struct:

```
let mut test: Account<MyPDAStruct> = Account::try_from(&ctx.remaining_accounts[0])
    .unwrap();
```

So far so good, this works and I am able to deserialize the `acccount`.

Now I would need to write to this account, which basically means that I need to serialize the data.

I found [this](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/src/anchor_lang/accounts/account.rs.html#335) reference:

```
impl<'info, T: AccountSerialize + AccountDeserialize + Owner + Clone> AccountsExit<'info>
    for Account<'info, T>
{
    fn exit(&self, program_id: &Pubkey) -> Result<()> {
        // Only persist if the owner is the current program.
        if &T::owner() == program_id {
            let info = self.to_account_info();
            let mut data = info.try_borrow_mut_data()?;
            let dst: &mut [u8] = &mut data;
            let mut writer = BpfWriter::new(dst); // notice this
            self.account.try_serialize(&mut writer)?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

It uses the [`BpfWriter`](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/src/anchor_lang/bpf_writer.rs.html) which then uses `sol_memcpy`.

However I am not able to import the `BpfWriter` from `anchor_lang`.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need these accounts to be mutable, the easier way is to pass them as regular accounts instead remaining accounts. For example if you will pass between 0 and 3 accounts, you might do something like:

```
    #[account(mut)]
    pub A: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub B: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub C: AccountInfo<'info>,
```

Where passing the default pubkey indicates the field is unused. This also allows you add constraints to check that the PDA is valid.

If you really need these in a Vec:

```
if ctx.accounts.A.key() != Pubkey::default(){
   vec.push(ctx.accounts.A.whatever);
}
```

Using `remaining_accounts` is a convenient shortcut, but remember that the maximum number of accounts is always limited by the max transaction size anyways. In practice you cannot exceed about 35 accounts in one tx, usually a little less with signers and other args.

Comment: What does `Pubkey::default()` evaluate to? vector of zero-ed bytes? What about the client side?

Comment: The default key is all zero bytes, and on the client side it is equivalent to `PublicKey.default` in the Solana web3 library.

Comment: checked and both on chain and off chain `Publickey::default()` evaluates to vec of`zeros`. Thanks!

Comment: what if the account is a PDA? In that case I would need to pass in some seeds, which differ in each Account. I can probably use `#instruction()`. Was wondering if there's a cleaner solution

Comment: It would be best to pass and check the seeds, but you could pass an `UncheckedAccount` if that's an issue for whatever reason

Answer (score 0):

Still unable to import `BpfWriter` from `anchor_lang` so in the meantime I just copied the `BpfWriter` code into a module in my project.

Notice that you don't really need to copy the whole code, you can just implement `Write` by your own.

```
use solana_program::program_memory::sol_memcpy;
use std::cmp;
use std::io::{self, Write};

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct BpfWriter<T> {
    inner: T,
    pos: u64,
}

impl<T> BpfWriter<T> {
    pub fn new(inner: T) -> Self {
        Self { inner, pos: 0 }
    }
}

impl Write for BpfWriter<&mut [u8]> {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        if self.pos >= self.inner.len() as u64 {
            return Ok(0);
        }

        let amt = cmp::min(
            self.inner.len().saturating_sub(self.pos as usize),
            buf.len(),
        );
        sol_memcpy(&mut self.inner[(self.pos as usize)..], buf, amt);
        self.pos += amt as u64;
        Ok(amt)
    }

    fn write_all(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> io::Result<()> {
        if self.write(buf)? == buf.len() {
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err(io::Error::new(
                io::ErrorKind::WriteZero,
                "failed to write whole buffer",
            ))
        }
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> io::Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to write in a remaining account? I am using try_from to get the remaining account. It is an account with a Vec where I want to push a value. The problem is that the value doesn't actually stores in the Vec although I dont get any error. I think I have to serialize it somehow