# Write on remaining_accounts

Tags: account

I'm trying to push a value into a remaining_account Vec.

Here it is my code: I have an Struct with a Vec<Pubkey> and I need to push a value.
I am using try_from to get the account info but I think I have to somehow serialize the push because otherwise it doesn't store the pubkey after pushing it.

Any ideas?

I have tried this but I get an "Already Borrowed" error on this line "data.serialize(&mut *pda_info.try_borrow_mut_data()?)?;"

```
#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct PdaStruct {
    pub addresses: Vec<Pubkey>,
    pub bump: u8,
}

fn add_pubkey(ctx: Context<SomeContext>){
. . .

let pda_info = &ctx.remaining_accounts[0].to_account_info();

let data_ref: &mut [u8] = &mut pda_info.try_borrow_mut_data()?;

let account_to_store: [u8; 32] = ctx.accounts.someaccount.key().to_bytes();

let data = data_ref.get_mut(13..45).unwrap();

data.copy_from_slice(&account_to_store);

data.serialize(&mut *pda_info.try_borrow_mut_data()?)?;

. . .
}
```

Comment: What you want to do is push a pubkey and modify the account space? correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think I have to borrow_mut_data and then serialize but not very sure how

Comment: i can see you have a mutable ref to `pda_info ` twice so that can be the issue

Answer (score 2):

I finally followed the steps in here: [Writing to remaining_accounts in Anchor](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2179/writing-to-remaining-accounts-in-anchor)

I made a module with de BpfWriter and impl the serialize in the PdaStruct.

A full example can be found here: https://cs.github.com/nosana-ci/nosana-programs/tree/5eb974eb8a4640a639ed53ce73081035541d7f44/programs
The common folder is where you will find writer.rs with the BpfWriter and inside programs/nosana-jobs/src/state.rs you can find the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you want to push a pubkey and then redefine the space I recommend using realloc.

Starting from this initial state:

```
    fn init_value(ctx: Context<Init>){
      let (_pda, bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[b"Init"], ctx.program_id);
      let init: &mut Account<PdaStruct> = &mut ctx.accounts.init;
      init.bump = bump;
      init.addresses = [].to_vec();
      init.len = 1 + 4 + 32;
    }

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Init<'info> {
    #[account(
     init, 
     seeds = [b"Init"], 
     bump, 
     payer = from, 
     space = PdaStruct::SIZE + 8)]
    pub init: Account<'info, PdaStruct>,
    /// CHECK: signer
    #[account(mut, signer)]
    pub from: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>
}

#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
 pub struct PdaStruct {
      pub addresses: Vec<Pubkey>,
      pub bump: u8,
      pub len: u32
  }

impl PdaStruct {
     pub const SIZE: usize = 1 + 4 + 32 
}
```

You will be able to use realloc to change the size of the account

```
    fn change_value(ctx: Context<Realloc>, key: Pubkey){
      let change: &mut Account<PdaStruct> = &mut ctx.accounts.change;
      init.addresses.push(key);
    }

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Realloc<'info> {
    #[account(
     mut, 
     seeds = [b"Init"],
     bump = change.bump,
     realloc = 8 + change.len as usize + 32,
     realloc::payer = from,
     realloc::zero = false,
     pub change: Account<'info, PdaStruct>,
     /// CHECK: signer
     #[account(mut, signer)]
     pub from: AccountInfo<'info>,
     pub system_program: Program<'info, System>
}

#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
 pub struct PdaStruct {
      pub addresses: Vec<Pubkey>,
      pub bump: u8,
      pub len: u32
  }

impl PdaStruct {
     pub const SIZE: usize = 1 + 4 + 32 
}
```

If you want to make it dynamic you can save the space variable in your account, or use `std::mem::size_of::()`

More info here https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/derive.Accounts.html

Comment: The problem is that I am not passing the account in the struct, I am passing it as a remaining account, then trying to deserialize, add the Pubkey to the Vec, and finally serialize.